# Is there a way to write custom attributes like x:Name or x:Shared in Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I guess the title explains it all.

I am looking for a way to extend xaml with custom attributes. I know there are x:Name, x:Key, x:Shared, x:Class but is there a way to write custom attributes.

Has anybody tried this? I am not looking for attached dependency properties.

I am looking for those extensions

Comment: What are you looking to do that attached properties don't give you?

Comment: For example attached properties can only be attached on dependency objects which means they cannot be placed inside ResourceDictionary or on types that do no inherit from dependency object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't.

The x:* directives are read by the XAML parser directly. Look at x:Name, or x:Key, for example. There is no corresponding attached property for these, and they both trigger a distinct, specific behavior in the parser.

When x:Name is found, the current [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is found and the item added to it, with the specified name as the key. Similar handling is done with the x:Key directive, using the IDictionary interface as you said.

And since WPF does not provide a way to extend the parser (which is a shame), what you asked is not possible.

Comment: I was afraid I couldn't. Is there any other way to attach data to non dependencyobject?

Comment: I'm afraid not... but you could create a dependency object wrapper for your data?!

Comment: Its about ResourceDictionaries.. I cant have dependency object as the top most item in a resource xaml file. Later I wont be able to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is the `MarkupExtension` class. Details on MSDN can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: MarkupExtension must be only used as value to a property. You cannot use them to store additional data. Its a good idea though :)